# React Native: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.json')

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I am trying to parse the response body in a json so I can save it in a state, I receive the error from the title. For some reason, the response.json is undefined. Here is my response:

```
16:28:30: Response {
16:28:30:   "_bodyInit": "\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNTE1MjQ4OTEwLCJleHAiOjE1MTUyNTAxMTAsImlhdCI6MTUxNTI0ODkxMH0.8zIX0PjC0XHBiHTtXlDvNxbOADj2NgtxK8zC-MqxoCg\"",
16:28:30:   "_bodyText": "\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNTE1MjQ4OTEwLCJleHAiOjE1MTUyNTAxMTAsImlhdCI6MTUxNTI0ODkxMH0.8zIX0PjC0XHBiHTtXlDvNxbOADj2NgtxK8zC-MqxoCg\"",
16:28:30:   "headers": Headers {
16:28:30:     "map": Object {
16:28:30:       "access-control-allow-credentials": Array [
16:28:30:         "true",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "cache-control": Array [
16:28:30:         "public, max-age=0",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "content-length": Array [
16:28:30:         "182",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "content-type": Array [
16:28:30:         "application/json; charset=utf-8",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "date": Array [
16:28:30:         "Sat, 06 Jan 2018 14:28:30 GMT",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "expires": Array [
16:28:30:         "-1",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "server": Array [
16:28:30:         "Microsoft-IIS/10.0",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "x-aspnet-version": Array [
16:28:30:         "4.0.30319",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:       "x-powered-by": Array [
16:28:30:         "ASP.NET",
16:28:30:       ],
16:28:30:     },
16:28:30:   },
16:28:30:   "ok": true,
16:28:30:   "status": 200,
16:28:30:   "statusText": undefined,
16:28:30:   "type": "default",
16:28:30:   "url": "url",
16:28:30: }
```

Here is the code where I receive the error:

```
export function loginAction(data) {
    return dispatch => Promise.all([
        dispatch(loginStarted()),
        loginService(data).then(response => {

            console.log(response);
            if (!response.ok) {
                Alert.alert('ERROR', 'User or password is incorrect');
                dispatch(loginFailed('User or password is incorrect'));
            }
            else {
                Alert.alert('OK', 'Login is a success');
            }
        }).then((response) => response.json()).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            dispatch(loginSuccess(response));
        })
    ]);
}
```

The error is received at the line where (response) => response.json() is.

Here is the fetch request:

```
export const loginService = (user) => {

    return fetch(`${httpApiUrl}/api/userdata/ReactVerify`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
};
```

I also tried response.text() instead of json(), but still it's undefined.
How can I get the text from _bodyInit, or what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Your first handler `loginService(data).then(response => {...` doesn't return anything, so the second one gets undefined.

Comment: You need to learn [how promises work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Then you will not make the coding error you have here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uh, why are you using two `.then` calls? The former callback does not return anything, so the chained promise resolves with `undefined` and that's exactly what the latter callback receives. Just use only one - and also don't call `response.json()` when the status was not ok.

```
loginService(data).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    if (!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('ERROR', 'User or password is incorrect');
        dispatch(loginFailed('User or password is incorrect'));
    } else {
        Alert.alert('OK', 'Login is a success');
        return response.json().then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            dispatch(loginSuccess(data));
        });
    }
})
```